# Arabic text in facebook graph api response

Tags: java, android, facebook

hey i'm trying to get a facebook page posts
my problem is a specific post contain english and arabic and english text
the arabic text returned as hex string like this

```
\u0641\u064a_\u0623\u0628\u0648\u0638\u0628\u064a\
```

even if i added "UTF-8" but this didn't do any thing

```
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
```

i tried to parse the response using apache common Hex class but i dont want to split the response and parse the arabic text individually.
and ideas on how i can do this

Note:Even if i tried same request on the browser i get same result only graph explorer show the text correctly

This is the JSON field which i need to parse correctly

```
"message":"Caption challenge: How would you describe this stunning view ? http:\/\/bit.ly\/1KhroPr\n\n\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0628\u062f\u0627\u0639 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0648\u0635\u0641: \u0643\u064a\u0641 \u064a\u0645\u0643\u0646\u0643 \u0648\u0635\u0641 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0647\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0630\u0647\u0644 #\u0641\u064a_\u0623\u0628\u0648\u0638\u0628\u064a\u061f\nhttp:\/\/bit.ly\/1GyiNJb"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was easier than i though just parsing the json object with

```
org.json
```

then i got the problem fixed

but if some one to parse the arabic text part individually
i found these [Apache common class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) are useful